# Hybrid Sorting - Quicksort & Insertion Sort

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort, insertion-sort

so I tried to implement an insertion algorithm that is supposed to compute on huge data sets with `QuickSort`, and eventually the recursion will lead to smaller subsets, and I once I reach a specific threshold (10 in here) I want to sort these small subsets with `Insertion Sort`. Well, it seemed I succeeded at first, since for elements < 100 it works, but I tried with > 1000 elements and it's all messed up, why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define CUTOFF 10

void 
swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *a;
}

void
insertion_sort(int arr[], int left, int right)
{

    int i,j;
    for(i=left+1; i<=right; i++)
    {
        int temp = arr[i];
        j = i;

        while(j>0 && arr[j-1]>temp)
        {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            j--;
        }

        arr[j] = temp;
    }

}

int 
median(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    int center = (left+right)/2;
    if(arr[left]>arr[center]){swap(&arr[left], &arr[center]);}
    if(arr[left]>arr[right]){swap(&arr[left],&arr[right]);}
    if(arr[center]>arr[right]){swap(&arr[center],&arr[right]);}
    swap(&arr[center], &arr[right]);
    return arr[right];
}

int
partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int pivot = median(arr, left, right);

    for(int j = left; j<right;j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]<pivot)
        {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    swap(&arr[i], &arr[right]);
    return i;
}

void
quicksort(int arr[], int left, int right)
{

    if(left+CUTOFF<=right)
    {
        int pivot = partition(arr, left, right);
        quicksort(arr, left, pivot-1);
        quicksort(arr, pivot+1, right);
    }
    else
    {
        insertion_sort(arr, left,right);
    }
    
}


int main()
{
    int test[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        test[i] = rand();
    }

    int size = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);
    quicksort(test,0,size-1);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", test[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The last line in your `swap` function should be `*b = temp;`. (If you compile with warnings enabled, which you should, you'll get a message about `temp` being unused.)

Comment: Damn, I didn't realize... How come it worked for smaller values tho? Thank you so much!

Comment: You would have see that there were many copies of the same values, but to see that you would need to print the pre-sort values and the post-sort values and check that they are not the same.

Comment: You don't need to call insertion sort at the depth of the qsort recursion. If you just qsort down to the threshold and the insertion sort the entire array after, you get the same behaviour and the logic is a little simpler. You won't swap between the chunks you leave I sorted with qsort, because all values in one chunk are smaller than all values on the other. Hs nothing to do with the error, it just makes the code a little simpler.

Comment: @ThomasMailund - it should be faster to call insertion sort at the depth of qsort recusrion because the data should already be loaded into cache.

Comment: @rcgldr True, but a final scan through the data, if the blocks are small, will also only access local data, and would also be cache efficient. And you would only need to hold one function in cache. I would expect the two solutions to be roughly equal in performance, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @ThomasMailund - quick sort and insertion sort functions are small, and the entire set of  quick sort + insertion sort functions would probably fit in the 32KB code cache of most X86 processors. For a larger array, doing insertion sort afterwards, would have to read data from main memory a second time, but overall not much of a performance hit.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right...